# triple pointer and memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management

**hello , 
i decared pointer to pointer in main**

and i need memory allocation using my function allocation

```
int main()
{ 

     Map **Store;
     allocation(&store);

)
```

i want to allocate dynamic memoiry use function allocation

like that :

```
void allocation(Map ***store)
{
     **store=(Map*)malloc(sizeof(Map)*6);
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
       *(store+i)=(Map**)malloc(sizeof(Map)*1000);
)
```

but not working

Comment: Obligatory link to [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
void allocation(Map ***store)
{
     *store = malloc(sizeof(Map*)*6);
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
       (*store)[i] = (Map*)malloc(sizeof(Map)*1000);
}
```